# Calculus derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education

What is the second derivative of $h(x)=g(f(x))$
I was able to find the first derivative which is $h'(x)=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$
I know for the second derivative we are going to need to use both the chain rule and product rule but I am unsure how

Comment: $h''(x)=g''(f(x))(f'(x))^{2}+g'(f(x))f''(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

$$h(x)=g(f(x))$$
$$h'(x)=g'(f(x))\times f'(x)$$
$$h''(x)=g''(f(x))\times f'(x)\times f'(x) + g'(f(x))\times f''(x)$$
$$h''(x)=g''(f(x))\times (f'(x))^2 + g'(f(x))\times f''(x)$$